# Error (invalid_client) sending a curl request through a windows command-line prompt

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-oauth2

## Disclaimer: I was forced to remove `http` prefixes from urls because my post was marked as a spam, so somewhere (mostly in pom.xml) links would look like `://localhost:8080`

And yes, I created custom
host entries in /etc/hosts in windows/system32/drivers folder

After logging into account, and granting consent:
[consent granting process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ffmh.png)

I getting a url with code parameter which I should use in a curl (to get my JWT via code).
Url example I getting (code paramater is different when I rerun my server or session but this is the exact thing I should use in curl):

```
http://127.0.0.1:9090/login/oauth2/code/taco-admin-client?code=ru3PTVCjkrlLYCVnoRIakoe7JH0GibmnOeH1U4TC-jj5yk9s7CwDiCyzwi1psL1DlKBBtkAI5cjJb-SWdk1R24qvFy3HyySHio1fGfGnTNoxyB4YEGgxQNBx2bn7XeLR&state=J9iwIMGikZZ4onflWHDfWlW9Hrn11eqm8CiRkih8fqU%3D
```

Trying to use a curl via windows command-line prompt (cmd):

```
curl localhost:9000/oauth2/token -H"Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d"grant_type=authorization_code" -d"redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:9090/login/oauth2/code/taco-admin-client" -d"code=BJXUaerI1KR6YKBQkCdQAu-5cJXgySXtKg09kW09KmSLGDfv_xy3D2BRU1NYWNvvOx7gmnSXjIB59XZ4HOJWJQncYt3s1c_6FpSI_3kK5V1g2-tGGobvVqevTHuNZ_ga" -u taco-admin-client:secret
```

## I'm getting an error

```
{"error":"invalid_client"}
```

Also tried to make it with -v attribute for more information, got :

```
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:9000...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 9000 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'taco-admin-client'
> POST /oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:9000
> Authorization: Basic dGFjby1hZG1pbi1jbGllbnQ6c2VjcmV0
> User-Agent: curl/8.0.1
> Accept: */*
> Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> Content-Length: 234
>
< HTTP/1.1 401
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: 0
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Fri, 17 Nov 2023 16:53:04 GMT
<
{"error":"invalid_client"}* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

## But, instead of error, i wanted to see a JSON response of a JWT which could look like this :

```
{
"access_token":"eyJraWQ...",
"refresh_token":"HOzHA5s...",
"scope":"deleteIngredients writeIngredients",
"token_type":"Bearer",
"expires_in":"299"
}
```

Don't pay attention to namings, i wanted to follow classes creation order (for myself). My configurations corresponding to the different servers (i won't add entities, repositories, etc., because the problem lies only in server configurations (main application still wokrs, but something's wrong with auth server)) :

Server with port 9000:

yml file :

```
#tag::portNineThousand[]
server:
  port: 9000
#end::portNineThousand[]

management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: '*'
```

Authentication Server Configuration classes  :

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class _S3_SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    @Order (Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)
    SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http)
            throws Exception {
        return http
                .authorizeRequests(authorizeRequests ->
                        authorizeRequests
                               .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .formLogin()
                .and().build();
    }

    @Bean
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService(_S32_UserRepository userRepo) {
        return username -> userRepo.findByUsername(username);
    }
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

```
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
public class _S4_AuthorizationServerConfig {

    @Bean
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    public SecurityFilterChain
    authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws
            Exception {
        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration
                .applyDefaultSecurity(http);
        return http
                .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .build();
    }


    @Bean
    public RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository(
            PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        RegisteredClient registeredClient =
                RegisteredClient.withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                        .clientId("taco-admin-client")
                        .clientSecret(passwordEncoder.encode("secret"))
                        .clientAuthenticationMethod(
                                ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC)
                        .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
                        .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.REFRESH_TOKEN)
                        .redirectUri("http://127.0.0.1:9090/login/oauth2/code/taco-admin-client") 
                        .scope("writeIngredients")
                        .scope("deleteIngredients")
                        .scope(OidcScopes.OPENID)
                        .clientSettings(
                                clientSettings -> clientSettings.requireUserConsent(true)
                        )
                        .build();
        return new InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository(registeredClient);
    }

    @Bean
    public ProviderSettings providerSettings() {
        return new ProviderSettings()
                .issuer("http://authserver:9000");
    }

}
```

JWK producer :

```
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
public class _S5_JWK_Producer {
    @Bean
    public JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource()
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        RSAKey rsaKey = generateRsa();
        JWKSet jwkSet = new JWKSet(rsaKey);
        return (jwkSelector, securityContext) -> jwkSelector.select(jwkSet);
    }
    private static RSAKey generateRsa() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        KeyPair keyPair = generateRsaKey();
        RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyPair.getPublic();
        RSAPrivateKey privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) keyPair.getPrivate();
        return new RSAKey.Builder(publicKey)
                .privateKey(privateKey)
                .keyID(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .build();
    }
    private static KeyPair generateRsaKey() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator =
                KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048);
        return keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
    }
    @Bean
    public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder(JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource) {
        return OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.jwtDecoder(jwkSource);
    }

}
```

Server with port 9090 :

yml file :

```
server:
  port: 9090

# tag::client_config[]
# tag::provider_config_0[]
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        # end::provider_config_0[]
        registration:
          taco-admin-client:
            provider: tacocloud
            client-id: taco-admin-client
            client-secret: secret
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            redirect-uri: "http://127.0.0.1:9090/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}"
            scope: writeIngredients,deleteIngredients,openid
        # end::client_config[]
        # tag::provider_config[]
        provider:
          tacocloud:
            issuer-uri: http://authserver:9000
# end::provider_config[]
```

Client-Server config:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests(
                        authorizeRequests -> authorizeRequests.anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .oauth2Login(
                        oauth2Login ->
                                oauth2Login.loginPage("/oauth2/authorization/taco-admin-client"))
                .oauth2Client(withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }

//This refers to other part, but maybe it would matter(given all classes containment)
    @Bean
    @RequestScope
    public IngredientService ingredientService(
            OAuth2AuthorizedClientService clientService) {
        Authentication authentication =
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

        String accessToken = null;

        if (authentication.getClass()
                .isAssignableFrom(OAuth2AuthenticationToken.class)) {
            OAuth2AuthenticationToken oauthToken =
                    (OAuth2AuthenticationToken) authentication;
            String clientRegistrationId =
                    oauthToken.getAuthorizedClientRegistrationId();
            if (clientRegistrationId.equals("taco-admin-client")) {
                OAuth2AuthorizedClient client =
                        clientService.loadAuthorizedClient(
                                clientRegistrationId, oauthToken.getName());
                accessToken = client.getAccessToken().getTokenValue();
            }
        }
        return new RestIngredientService(accessToken);
    }

}
```

My Resource Server (and the main application) with port 8080:

yml file:

```
taco:
  orders:
    pageSize: 10 #configuration properties for constant value

spring:
  data:
    rest:
      base-path: /data-api
  datasource:
    generate-unique-name: false
    name: tacocloud

  # tag::jwkSetUri[]
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          jwk-set-uri: http://localhost:9000/oauth2/jwks
# end::jwkSetUri[]
```

RestFull controller of this server (maybe it would matter):

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path="/api/ingredients", produces="application/json")
@CrossOrigin(origins="http://localhost:8080") 
public class _S51_REST_IngredientController {
    private _S19_Spring_JDBC_IngredientRepository repo;
    @Autowired
    public _S51_REST_IngredientController(@Qualifier("_S19_JdbcIngredientIngredientRepository") _S19_Spring_JDBC_IngredientRepository repo) {
        this.repo = repo;
    }
    @GetMapping
    public Iterable<_S6_Application_Domain_Class_Ingredient> allIngredients() {
        return repo.findAll();
    }


    @PostMapping
    @PreAuthorize("#{hasRole('ADMIN')}")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public _S6_Application_Domain_Class_Ingredient saveIngredient(@RequestBody _S6_Application_Domain_Class_Ingredient ingredient) {
        return repo.save(ingredient);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    @PreAuthorize("#{hasRole('ADMIN')}")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    public void deleteIngredient(@PathVariable("id") String ingredientId) {
        repo.deleteById(ingredientId);
    }
}
```

And pom.xmls (if needed). All url prefixes were been removed:

for 9090 :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 s://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.4</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>client-server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>client-server</name>
    <description>client-server</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <image>
                        <builder>paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-base:latest</builder>
                    </image>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

For 9000:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 s://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.4</version>
        <relativePath/> 
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring_authorization_server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>spring_authorization_server</name>
    <description>spring_authorization_server</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.experimental</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.28</version> 
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <image>
                        <builder>paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-base:latest</builder>
                    </image>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

For 8080:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 s://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Spring_Based_Module</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Spring_Based_Module</name>
    <description>Spring_Based_Module</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency> 
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.28</version> 
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>

                <configuration> 
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>

            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```